# Vectors on Different Coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the product of vectors coordinated relative to a given coordinate frame, defined by

$\vec{a}\square\vec{b}=((a_{1},b_{1})\square(a_{2},b_{2})):=(a_{1}b_{1},a_{2}b_{2})$

Explain why that in the context of vectors this is no good.

My work:

I think that it is no good because if you change the coordinate system, you may change the vector. (Like a vector in Cartesian coordinates would be a different vector in polar coordinates [Not a 100% sure about that, but seems to make sense])

If anyone could expand as to why this is true, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just wanted to note, that as far as I know, $\square$ is not an actual operator and is just used for convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I'll give it a go as no-one else has.

Whenever you define any operation it would be nice if it could satisfy certain basic properties. For example, in a product, it would be nice to have the existence of a (unique) multiplicative identity. If I take $(2,3)$ I would like to have a vector $(x,y)$ such that

$$(2,3) \star (x,y) = (2,3). \tag{1}$$

Using your product definition, I would need to solve:

$$(6,xy) = (2,3).$$

Assuming equality is defined component-wise, there is no $(x,y)$ satisfying $(1)$. Of course, what properties you'd like any operation to satisfy is dependent on what you're doing so asking whether the operation is "no good" really depends what you're doing with it.

Cartesian and  Polar Coordinates are two different ways of representing the same vector. If you have a vector $(x,y)$ in cartesian coordinates than its polar coordinate representation is $(r,\theta)$ where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\theta$ is the angle (counterclockwise) from the $x$-axis. Again, depending on what you're doing one might be more useful or easier to work with than the other.

Hope this helps!